# 'The alias is already in use' when editing a node that had an alias generated programmatically

Tags: 8, uri, path-aliases

I'm currently using an event subscriber to latch onto an event from a module that creates and/or updates nodes. I'm programmatically setting the url alias based on a user inputted field by doing the following

```
$path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save("/node/" . $node->id(), $url_alias, "en");
```

It works but when I open the node and attempt to edit it, I get the message

> The alias is already in use

When I try to save it. Is there something I'm missing? Does a field on the actual node have to be edited as well?

I'm also using pathauto if that has any effect.

UPDATE: I just noticed that whenever that aliased is saved it generates 4 entries in the URL alias list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out whenever you perform this

```
\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save("/node/" . $node->id(), $url_alias, "en");
```

It generates a new alias every time even if the path alias already exists. I was able to resolve the issue by performing checks to see if the path already exists like so:

```
if (!\Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->pathHasMatchingAlias('/node/' . $node->id()) && !empty($node->id())) {
    $path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save("/node/" . $node->id(), $url_alias, "en");
}
```